# function returns error that it is declared when trying to call it

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using a stateful widget like down below. I first tried to call `log("something")` and I got the error `log must have a method body because _ProfilePageState isn't abstract.`

then I created a function naming it `userInfoFunction()` and put the `log` inside so the error dissappears. I try to call the function with `userInfoFunction();` yet I get the error

```
20:8: Context: Previous declaration of 'userInfoFunction'.
  void userInfoFunction() {
```

Of course I declared it to call it later on in the next lines, what does this error tell me ? What can I do about this ?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:developer';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:jwt_decoder/jwt_decoder.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:velocity_x/velocity_x.dart';
import 'register.dart';

class ProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  //create a variable to get the data from the first page then register.
  final info;
  const ProfilePage({@required this.info,Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ProfilePage> createState() => _ProfilePageState();
}

class _ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {

  //log("old try");

  void userInfoFunction() {
    log("inside login");
  }
  userInfoFunction();
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot call a function directly in a class, you must call it from another function.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:developer';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
 

  State<MyApp> createState() => MyAppState();  
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    userInfoFunction(); // this will be called once the widged is inserted inside the widget tree
  }
  
  void userInfoFunction() {
    log("inside login");
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: TextButton(onPressed: userInfoFunction, child: Text('Log message manually')),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```